# Check if battery optimization is enabled or not for an app

Tags: android, powermanager, android-powermanager

Android 6 and 7 have some power optimizations (doze mode) which restrict app networking when device is not used.

User may disable optimization mode for any app in Battery settings:

[image: android settings screenshot]

Is it possible to check if optimization is enabled for my app or not? I need to ask user to disable optimization for better app functionality, but I don't know how to check it programatically.

Comment: Note that it's not allowed to ask user to whitelist your app unless it satisfies the requirements here: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#whitelisting-cases

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This one was a bit tricky to track down: here's what you are looking for

[PowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations())

Comment: in case you want to be  able to get user to flip it: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

Comment: Does this apply for manufacturer modified ROMs too or only for Nexus/Pixel/A1 builds?

Comment: @EfiMK I couldn't do a comprehensive testing but I can confirm that `PowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations()` method is working on Samsung and Huawei devices. I would say it's available for any manufacturer ROM.

Answer (score 68):

**Add this permission in your manifest.**

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

> Request White-list / optimization enabled  your app

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes it works perfectly :D But only thing is that the app will be rejected from playstore and you'll lose all your business!

Comment: @RohitTP Can you please elaborate why adding this check in the app makes it a candidate for a rejection from PlayStore?

Comment: Well I guess, as I have checked. Adding permission  in the manifest is not required if you just want to check battery optimization and display a message to the user.

Comment: @sud007 'ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS' is a dangerous permission. Google doesn't like having apps having this anywhere inside their code(https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby). This permission & action is a bit dangerous since if we add this we allow the app to directly show an android pop up asking user to turn off battery optimizations for this app.
Instead, what you should do is have 'ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS' which takes user to list of apps where he has to search for your app & disable battery optimisations manually.

Comment: @RohitTP Yes buddy I checked all the details about the same and got educated about the gravity, and hence added my second comment. Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: For xiaumi 8 this doesn't work (I got activity is not found, even I put in manifest, and do some safeguard check).

Comment: some apps like true caller gets this permission by default, without asking the user to enable it, how is this possible?

Comment: probably money and nepotism

Comment: @SamerAlkhatib setting the app as an "Default App" -> True Caller is a Phone App. WILL turn off battery optimisations. I noticed that with our app. from the moment you set it as default, it sets it to "Not Optimised"

Comment: after granting battery OPTIMIZATIONS permission  this is not woking

Comment: @RohitTP According to google docs, It's not a problem if the core function of the app is adversely affected

Answer (score 42):

**How to write this in Kotlin**

1. Check if optimization is enabled

```kotlin
    /**
     * return true if in App's Battery settings "Not optimized" and false if "Optimizing battery use"
     */
    fun isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(context: Context): Boolean {
        val pwrm = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        val name = context.applicationContext.packageName
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return pwrm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(name)
        }
        return true
    }
```

2. Check if Optimization enabled, open optimizations `Activity`

```kotlin
    fun checkBattery() {
        if (!isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations() && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val name = resources.getString(R.string.app_name)
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Battery optimization -> All apps -> $name -> Don't optimize", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why ">= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1" ?
ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS was added in Android M.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the complete solution. Works like a charm!

Comment: you're going to need [REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS) permission for that second part to work

Comment: Yup like lasec0203 has pointed out, please add     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
to your manifest.

Comment: According to CommonsWare, If you want to use ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, to lead the user straight to a page specific for your app and the whitelist, you need to request REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS in the manifest, but you do not need to use runtime permissions code for it. If you want to avoid the permission, use ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS instead. So if you are using above answer you will not need REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission.

Answer (score 17):

Sample Code :

```
 PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (pm != null && !pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getPackageName())) {
                    askIgnoreOptimization();
                } else {
                   // already ignoring battery optimization code here next you want to do
                }
            } else {
           // already ignoring battery optimization code here next you want to do
            }
```

**Declare static variable**

```
private static final int IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_REQUEST = 1002;
```

**show dialog for BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS**

```
 private void askIgnoreOptimization() {

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_REQUEST);
        } else {
            openNextActivity();
        }
    }
```

also need to add permission to manifest file i.e as below

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

Maybe this code is helpful to you!

Comment: @yogesh how to get to know if he has tapped Allow/Deny and where?

Comment: @Ramesh you can verify on onActivityResult

Comment: @YogeshRathi I am developing app using React Native. So, I need to return boolean in the askIgnoreOptimization() method itself where I am startingActivity.

Comment: @Ramesh I am not sure of React Native, If you find an answer, please free to update the question

Comment: @Ramesh did you find a solution? This is exactly where I'm stuck as well

Comment: @Keselme I fixed this issue by using AppState. Using AppState, I was able to detect if App is in foreground or background. When the state changes from Background to Foreground, I check if permission is given or not in the screen. For some devices like Xiomi, we may need to add some delay and check the permission state as it may return always false.

Comment: @Ramesh, If you're still intreated, I think I have a solution that doesn't require the AppState thing.
Make your module implement `ActivityEventListener`. Then add it as a listener on your module's context. Then call for `startActivityForRestult` and implement `onActivityResult`. Here you can check if the permission is granted and resolve it via promise. I'm pretty sure it works, though I'm still testing different scenarios with this approach