# How to whitelist my Android app to China manufacturer like Xiaomi, Oppo, etc

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, whitelist

I know this is a really old question, but I don't see a clearly answer. Any solution about keeping android app running in background on china devices seems to be not working, so I think about contacting these manufacturer to whitelist my app. Can anyone show me how to do that?

P/s: I know an app can run in background without whitelist (I'm not sure about this, but it's not in list app with auto-start permission when I check), that's Zalo (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zing.zalo), another app can run in background on Oppo device, but not on Xiaomi device(Xiaomi Redmi 4X, with Android 7.1.2, MIUI Global 9.2), that's VN Ngay nay(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xb.topnews), so I still hope there's a way to keep app running in background, please comment if you know, thanks!

Comment: AFAIK There is no way to turn on `AutoStart`. You need send the user to setting so that they can manually turn it on. And i can not say much about These devices i also faced some weird behavior also on these devices. Like on Reboot i was not able to receive any notifications unless i open my app manually once .

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9510829/4748607)

Comment: @ADM I know that way but it's not a good solution. 2 apps I mentioned above don't need to turn on auto-start permission, and also not in list app with auto-start permission available by default like Facebook, Messenger,..but they still can run in background. I don't know how can they do that

Comment: @NiravBhavsar that's not a solution. There are too many China device, I can't block them all.

Comment: this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50291806/7579041

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that, unless you contract XiaoMi and other mobile phone manufacturers for Business cooperation 。
I am used to be a developer in XiaoMi,and exactly I wirte some code about this. I am very sorry to say, as I know,a normal android developer can do nothing for this.

Comment: @Tiến Nguyễn Hữu   You can posted a new topic  on http://en.miui.com/forum.php to contact them. The developers of XiaoMi see the forum every day.

Answer (score 0):

job scheduler,firebase dispatcher like services will work in the background so you can use these services to run your service in the background

Comment: Did you try it on China device?

Comment: in xiaomi devices. yes but the version of MIUI updated with many battery optimizations so I recommend you to try this out. you can periodically call this services so it will restart the service even it's killed by the system

Comment: it will not wotk in oreo version of chisese roms. I tried them all

Answer (score -2):

```
'<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />'
```

Add these two permissions in your manifest file it may work.