# how to enable floating notification and lock screen notification in xamarin android(Java or Kotlin is okay)

Tags: java, c#, android, kotlin, xamarin

I make simple notification android app using xamarin,
i want floating notification and lock screen notification
[image]

l add users permission in manifest, also i read all reference document about notification channel however i don't know how to enable floating notification and lock screen notification in code

outlook, gmail etc. some app enable all notification when it installed

[image]

[image]

[image]

above screenshot is my app

i want enable all notification when installed my app
necessarily Even if it is not in xamarin, a solution using kotlin or java is fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For `floating notification`, you should change Notification priority or NotificationChannel importance.**

**Android 5.0 - Android 7.1**

Set notification priority to `NotificationPriority.High` or `NotificationPriority.Max`.

```
builder.SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High)
```

Set ringtone and vibrations. You can use SetDefaults.

```
 // Turn on sound if the sound switch is on:                 
                notification.Defaults |= NotificationDefaults.Sound;

            // Turn on vibrate if the sound switch is on:                 
                notification.Defaults |= NotificationDefaults.Vibrate;
```

**Android 8.0 and higher**

Set notification channel priority to NotificationImportance.High or NotificationImportance.Max.

```
 var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID1, name, NotificationImportance.Max)
        {
            Description = description
        };
```

**For `lock notifications`, you could set the Visibility.**

Beginning with Android 5.0, the visibility setting is available to control how much notification content appears on the secure lock screen.

- `NotificationVisibility.Public` – The full content of the notification
  is displayed on the secure lock screen.
- `NotificationVisibility.Private` – Only essential information is displayed on the secure lock screen (such as the notification icon and the name of the app that posted it), but the rest of the notification's details are hidden. All notifications default to  NotificationVisibility.Private.

Comment: oh sorry my comment is to late, i changed notification importance and notificationvisiblity but i can get floating notification and lockscreen notification. i think change app notification settings. Is there any way i can change the notification settings through programming?

Comment: Could it be the problem that my test device is a Xiaomi?

Comment: Do you mean you could get floating notification and lockscreen notification? Which notification settings you want to change through programming?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo.
I did all the things required by the various articles. they said i should change lockscreen visibility, Notification Importance. but  i can't get floating notification and lockscreen notification. I guess. In the notificationTest app picture above, floating notifications and lockscreen notifications are turned off. then if i turn on it, maybe i can get notifications. if you know how to turn on it, please tell me

Comment: The seetings for the app would not affect. Have you tried my code? If the code still does work, could you provide the code you used for the notification?

Comment: Further investigation revealed that on xiaomi devices, apps that are not registered in the white list must be set by the user.

Comment: Your answer is correct. problem was just the Xiaomi device

Comment: Hi @Sunday, could you give me a link on where I can read about your further investigation on white listed app on xiaomi device?

Thank you

Comment: https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51257052/how-to-whitelist-my-android-app-to-china-manufacturer-like-xiaomi-oppo-etc
https://c.mi.com/thread-1545043-1-0.html
I saw above document