# vivo and oppo device not receiving the push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

Recently i made a android app and released in Google playstore and i got some complaints like not receiving the pushnotification in my device. After that we found the device OPPO and VIVO not receiving the notification.

Option given in mobile like SETTING -> AUTOSTART-> SELECT THE APP -> ENABLE IT THE NOTIFICATION after that you will get the notification. But this exercise we need to do the manually instead of that whether any possibilities to enable this notification via programmatic.

Any ideas and feedback to resolve this issues.

Comment: This will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50291806/7579041