# FCM Notification not working on some devices when application is killed or not in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Did some research on making FCM notification work some devices when the application is killed by the user(swiped away by the user from the app tray) or killed by the system OS but did not find any solution would appreciate if you can provide with solution or tell me what i am dong wrong. The notification is a data payload

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String payload = "",notification_message = "", channelId ="", channelName="AAA", channelDescription="";
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        String title = null, body = null;
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("REMOTE_DATA",remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        }

        if(remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
            if(remoteMessage.getData().get("title") != null) 
               title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");

            if(remoteMessage.getData().get("message") != null) 
               body = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

            if(remoteMessage.getData().get("channelName") != null) 
               channelName = remoteMessage.getData().get("channelName");
        }
    }

    //Setting up Notification channels for android O and above
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived: => " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

        if(notificationChannels.containsKey(channelName)) {
            JSONObject channelData = (JSONObject) notificationChannels.get(channelName);
            try {
                channelId = channelData.getString("channelId");
                channelName = channelData.getString("channelName");
                channelDescription = channelData.getString("channelDescription");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(channelId);
            if (notificationChannel == null)
                setupChannel(channelId, channelName, channelDescription);
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + title);
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + body);
    if(title != null && body != null) {
        apptivity_variable.createNotification(channelId,title, body);
        db.insertNotification(title, body, remoteMessage.getData().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: which device you r using?

Comment: This is somewhat related to your issue, it's just that Chinese-made phones are notorious for killing apps. Please read solutions here: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: @amin xiaomi phone android 9.0

Answer (score 1):

Try registering another service to identify the app in the background to trigger the service

```
public class FirebaseBackgroundService extends BroadcastReceiver{

  private static final String TAG = "FirebaseService";

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "I'm in!!!");

    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
      for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
        Object value = intent.getExtras().get(key);
        Log.e("FirebaseDataReceiver", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("gcm.notification.body") && value != null) {
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          Intent backgroundIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundSyncJobService.class);
          bundle.putString("push_message", value + "");
          backgroundIntent.putExtras(bundle);
          context.startService(backgroundIntent);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, don't forget to register it in your manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name=".FirebaseBackgroundService" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time but I'm not sure it is going to get to this block of code... let me give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and after searching and working around, I have found that user need to enable autostart and battery optimization permission manually for more details refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50291806/7579041) link

This issue is generally coming most of the Chinese phones to optimize battery etc.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50291806/7579041) link will solve your problem

Comment: this did not work for me
i have tried it but no luck at all
can not even find autostart on the phone
would appreciate your response

I am in Nigeria this question needs upvote has i can not find solution to this

Comment: I dont have time right now, I will update my answer for sure

Comment: Still on this issue

Comment: fixed the issue? or you need me to help out?

Answer (score 0):

There are two different types of push messages priorities in FCM: normal priority and high priority. Only high priority pushes will wake your application up when it's in background and is the subject of Doze Mode restrictions. You can read more about it in [this article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/09/notifying-your-users-with-fcm.html)

To make priority of your push message high, you have to add this section to the body of your push message:

```
"android":{"priority":"high"}
```

More information about push messages is available [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: Thanks for your response but nothing has worked. before now, it works on some android devices i am sure of a Nokia phone when the application is in background or doze mode but not working on phones like tecno, huawei, xiaomi, etc. even after all you recommend me to do

Comment: Could you add an example of your push message?

Comment: this is the pushMessage object example:
{"to":"token","android":{"priority":"high"},"data":{"title":"titleName","body":"detail"},"notification":{"title":"titleName","body":"detail"}}

Comment: Still on this issue