# Is there any way to check whether my application has auto start permission in android

Tags: android

I am trying to check whether the user already has an autostart permission to avoid the permission dialog.

Comment: If you are asking about the Auto Start Option some Manufactures has .. You can't check this .. To Check Battery   optimization status see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256501/check-if-battery-optimization-is-enabled-or-not-for-an-app).

Comment: Check out this may be it will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366231/how-to-check-miui-autostart-permission-programmatically

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to verify that the autostart option is enabled or disabled in your app. What you can do is, you can ask the user for enabling it manually when the user opens the app for the first time.

You can redirect the user to autostart permission's settings page for enabling your app using the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
    } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
    } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
    } else if ("Letv".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
    } else if ("Honor".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
    }

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if  (list.size() > 0) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have already used this manual option.

Comment: the question is to verify if auto start permission is enabled